# Installing gem5

Tags: software-installation, gem

I am trying to install gem5 using the below documentation:
https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/building/

But in the documentation, the below commands does not work:

```
python3 'which scons' build/X86/gem5.opt -j9
```

The error I was getting is below:

```
python3: can't open file 'which scons': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It would be very kind of you if someone guide me in the installation of  gem5 and provide me some links to learn about gem5.

After Installing gem5, I tried testing it with a below command and I got the error as shown below:
[image]

Please help me how to test it so that I can confirm that the installation is correct.

Comment: Thank you @guiverc. My OS is ubuntu 20.04. I have installed ubuntu using virtual box. Please guide me to correct portal  of stackoverflow if my question is not suitable here.

Comment: Could you post the complete error message?  This helps much to identify the problem.

Comment: Thank you @MarcVanhoomissen. Updated the question with error message.

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen. Your commands worked. Please provide some link to learn about gem5?

Comment: Google, gem5 doc : https://www.gem5.org/documentation/ ... and every time you click  NEXT a new page opens. ~30 pages ?

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem5, Ubuntu 20.04 https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/building

Build requirements ...
`sudo apt install build-essential scons swig protobuf-c-compiler golang-goprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-c-dev libprotobuf-dev libhdf5-dev libpng-dev ruby-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev valgrind python3-dev`

```
git clone https://github.com/gem5/gem5.git  
cd gem5/
scons build/X86/gem5.opt

## other typical build commands:
 scons build/ARM/gem5.opt
 scons build/ARM/gem5.fast
```

---

https://www.gem5.org/getting_started/ → example test

```
cd gem5/    
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/learning_gem5/part1/simple.py
```

replies

```
Starting simulation...
Hello world!
```

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen. Your comments helped me in installation. But I am still not able to test the installation. I edited the question and got the error that gem5.opt not found. Please guide me how to test the installation.

Comment: Example command, please see the edited answer. ........ The executable `gem5.opt` is not in a system PATH such as /usr/bin/ and cannot be run with `$ gem5.opt`

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen. Your answer gives a correct installation and produces a Hello World result.

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen This steps of installing gem5 works in ubuntu 20.04. Do the same steps works on ubuntu 22.04 (latest one) or will it be little different.

Comment: https://github.com/gem5/gem5 : I don't see any essential updates. 22.04: The failed test build I made 4 months ago may show the same today. I will do another build .... within the next days.

Comment: `gem5` :  The build script SConstruct got updated (and Ubuntu 22.04 got a couple of relevant updates), so no issues at building gem5 now.

Comment: Thank you @KnudLarsen for this great help.

Comment: Hi @KnudLarsen. I want to run MIPS processor on gem5 but there are no tutorials regarding this. It would be great if you can point me to some resource or guide to execute some sample program on MIPS using gem5. Should I post a new question for this?

Comment: Generally, please read the file README. .... Simulate MIPS: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/stable/build_opts/MIPS